# how DTMF option recognize more than one digit in ivr bot application

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, ivr

How to recognize a DTMF option as "123"(more than a digit) in IVR bot application.Basically DTMF accepts like press 1,2,3 not as "123".why?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.
Can you tell us more about your 'IVR bot' application and its limits ?
On standard IVR systems it should be easy to manage the 2 cases (digit by digit or get a number/digits sequence).